# Drupal Commerce: How to create coupon that will give first month free?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

In Drupal Commerce, how can I create a coupon code that will deduct the first month free for select products?

Basically we have a set of services available that we want to give the first month free.  We'd like a code that when entered, will provide the first month free.

I am imagining it would have to see product A is $5.99 and subtract $5.99 from the cart and product B is $9.99 and subtract $9.99 from the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Commerce Recurring module. It allows you to configure "initial price" which is the price charged for the first order interval, and then a regular price which is charged for all subsequent periods.

You already want Recurring, anyway, in order to handle the monthly orders automatically. If you add Card On File, you can automatically bill the customer.

Comment: Good idea but our billing is handled externally.  So I was leaning towards a solution that used a one-time discount, like Commerce Coupon but I am open to suggestions,

Answer (score 0):

**Swlljoe** suggestion is great but currently this module is **only available in dev version** and it's not recommended to use it on a live environment.

Those are great resources that can help you achieve what you are looking for: https://www.drupal.org/resource-guides/drupal-for-membership-websites

Specifically [Membership Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/membership_entity) and [Membership Entity Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/membership_entity_commerce). Both modules are actively maintained.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The way our site works, we generate an order in Drupal and then the order is sent via XML to our payment processing site and then everything is handled there. Not sure this solution will work.  I was hoping to leverage the Commerce Coupon module to get a solution.